# How we print the individual data if data is posting through rasberrypie in urlencode formate

Tags: php

The data is posting to URL- http://block.com/device/index.php , and the data is posting like http://block.com/device/index.php deviceid=B8%3A27%3AEB%3A49%3A1C%3ADE&value0=0.44295856&value1=67.95392&value2=0.44693676&value3=0.44265252
03-26 18:07:45.702 in url encode . so how we decode that url and print the individual data in php code.

Comment: please help to get the individual data from encoded URL.

Comment: which individual data you are talking about?

Comment: you mean you need deviceid , value , value2 ... etc

Comment: I am talking about deviceid=B8%3A27%3AEB%3A49%3A1C%3ADE&value0=0.44295856&value1=67.95392&value2=0.44693676&value3=0.44265252.

Comment: yes deviceid,value0,value1,value2 and value3

Answer (score 0):

you can get individual values using `$_GET` superglobal variable of php.

```
$deviceId = $_GET['deviceid']; //between the 'deviceid' is from url
$value0 = $_GET['value0'];
```

same for value 1 and 2
then you can print them

`echo $deviceid;`

so on

Comment: This is showing nothing data in the browser when we use this.

Answer (score 0):

ty this

```
$str="http://block.com/device/index.php&deviceid=B8%3A27%3AEB%3A49%3A1C%3ADE&value0=0.44295856&value1=67.95392&value2=0.44693676&value3=0.44265252";

$url = parse_url(urldecode($str));

$result = null;

$res = parse_str($url['path'], $result);

return $result;
```

live results:
https://implode.io/SqLqX9

Comment: Actually the data is post to http://block.com/device/index.php from rasbeerypie in URL encode form so we don't know the URL so how get that data in php code individually like deviceid,  value. But data is posting from the raspberry pie device is like http://block.com/device/index.php deviceid=B8%3A27%3AEB%3A49%3A1C%3ADE&value0=0.44295856&value1=67.95392&value2=0.44693676&value3=0.44265252 03-26 18:07:45.702 so how we get that.

Comment: One thing to understand @DeepakKumar is there a space after `index.php` or you are adding that ?